# JNA passed values not updating

Tags: java, c, dll, jna

I'm very new to JNA. Im having an issue where im passing a Structure to a library call that updates some variables. When I do it directly in the C code from a main method it works, but when I try to access this using JNA the values are not updated.

The values im trying to get are: ser, serName, hw, hwName, oem, oemName

The method i'm trying to access in JNA:

```
__declspec(dllexport) Bool _cdecl
GetSN(
        DevProgramInfo           * pDevProgInfo,
        unsigned char              sessionID) {


    unsigned char                   * pCmd;
    unsigned short                    cmdLen = 0;
    Platform_Access_Get_SN_Payload     * pBufGetSN;

    pCmd = (unsigned char *)&Cmd;
    pBufGetSN = (Platform_Access_Get_SN_Payload *)&Payload;

    ClearMsgHeader((Message *)pCmd);

    Platform_Get_SN(pCmd, sessionID, &cmdLen, (unsigned char *)pBufGetSN);
    USBWriteToDevice(&pDevProgInfo->deviceInfo, pCmd, &cmdLen);
    USBReadFromDevice(&pDevProgInfo->deviceInfo, pCmd);
    Platform_Get_SN(pCmd, sessionID, &cmdLen, (unsigned char *)pBufGetSN);

    pDevProgInfo->sn.sn.ser = pBufGetSN->resp.ser;
    strcpy((char *)pDevProgInfo->sn.sn.serName, (char *)pBufGetSN->resp.serName);
    pDevProgInfo->sn.sn.hw = pBufGetSN->resp.hw;
    strcpy((char *)pDevProgInfo->sn.sn.hwName, (char *)pBufGetSN->resp.hwName);
    pDevProgInfo->sn.sn.oem = pBufGetSN->resp.oem;
    strcpy((char *)pDevProgInfo->sn.sn.oemName, (char *)pBufGetSN->resp.oemName);

    return TRUE;
}
```

my JNA declaration of this method is

```
public boolean GetSN(DevProgramInfo devInfo, byte sessionID);
```

I built the structure in Java, here is the "sn.sn" creating in java

```
public class mySN extends Union {
    /// C type : field_struct

    public field_struct field;
    /// C type : sn_struct
    public sn_struct sn;
    /// <i>native declaration : line 3</i>
    /// <i>native declaration : line 3</i>

    public static class field_struct extends Structure {
        /// unique to each pid+version+variant

        public NativeLong sequence;
        public byte variant;
        public byte version;
        public short pid;

        public field_struct() {
            super();
        }

        protected List getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList("sequence", "variant", "version", "pid");
        }

        public field_struct(NativeLong sequence, byte variant, byte version, short pid) {
            super();
            this.sequence = sequence;
            this.variant = variant;
            this.version = version;
            this.pid = pid;
        }

        public static class ByReference extends field_struct implements Structure.ByReference {
        };

        public static class ByValue extends field_struct implements Structure.ByValue {
        };

        public boolean copy(field_struct fieldInfo) {
            this.sequence = fieldInfo.sequence;
            this.variant = fieldInfo.variant;
            this.version = fieldInfo.version;
            this.pid = fieldInfo.pid;
            return true;
        }
    };
    /// <i>native declaration : line 9</i>
    /// <i>native declaration : line 9</i>

    public static class sn_struct extends Structure {

        public NativeLong ser;
        public byte[] serName = new byte[20];
        public NativeLong hw;
        public byte[] hwName = new byte[20];
        public NativeLong oem;
        public byte[] oemName = new byte[20];

        public sn_struct() {
            super();
        }

        protected List getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList("ser", "serName", "hw", "hwName", "oem", "oemName");
        }
        public sn_struct(NativeLong ser, byte serName[], NativeLong hw, byte hwName[], NativeLong oem, byte oemName[]) {
            super();
            this.ser = ser;
            if (serName.length != this.serName.length) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong array size !");
            }
            this.serName = serName;
            this.hw = hw;
            if (hwName.length != this.hwName.length) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong array size !");
            }
            this.hwName = hwName;
            this.oem = oem;
            if (oemName.length != this.oemName.length) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong array size !");
            }
            this.oemName = oemName;
        }

        public static class ByReference extends sn_struct implements Structure.ByReference {
        };

        public static class ByValue extends sn_struct implements Structure.ByValue {
        };
    };

    public mySN() {
        super();
    }
    /// @param sn C type : sn_struct

    public mySN(sn_struct sn) {
        super();
        this.sn = sn;
        setType(sn_struct.class);
    }
    /// @param field C type : field_struct

    public mySN(field_struct field) {
        super();
        this.field = field;
        setType(field_struct.class);
    }

    public static class ByReference extends mySN implements Structure.ByReference {
    };

    public static class ByValue extends mySN implements Structure.ByValue {
    };
}
```

When I use the code

```
myJNA.getSN(devInfo, (byte) 0);
```

All of the variables (ser, serName, hw, hwName, oem, oemName) are 0's. Ive been stumped on this issue for about a week now and I cant seem to figure out the issue.

When I add printf's to the DLL the correct values are generated into the structures there, but I do not get those values in the objects in Java.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a `Union`.  Unless you set the "active" type, JNA can only automatically read back primitive fields (you wouldn't want it to read back a 'const char*` field of a union if it was really just an integer with value zero).

Call [`Union.setType(Class)`](http://twall.github.io/jna/3.5.2/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Union.html#setType%28java.lang.Class%29) before the call if you know it; otherwise call it after the native call followed by `Structure.read()`.

Comment: This was exactly the issue! Thanks so much for your help. That issue was driving me absolutely mad with how much time I've spent modifying code. The solution was clearly more simple then expected!

Comment: I do appear to have a different issue now though. The last 4 Bytes in the C code are the first 4 Bytes in the Java code followed by a bunch of garbage.

Comment: You'll need to be more explicit.  "C code" generally doesn't have a "last 4 Bytes" unless you're talking about the source file.

Comment: Sorry I have been more clear. I'm watching serName and the value in the C code after I call GetSN is "0000000000000000009" and the value I get inside the Java equivalent is "0009________$0_____~" (underscored = spaces) insides the unions structure

Comment: Correction on serName values. In C code its "0000000000000009\0\0\0\0" Java serName is  "0009________$0_____~" (underscores = spaces)

Comment: If you call `Structure.toString()` with the system property `jna.dump_memory` set, you might more easily see how/where individual bytes are being shifted, and if you need to tweak alignment and/or add padding to the structure.  Seeing the original struct definition(s) side by side with your proposed JNA mappings would also make things clearer.

Comment: I've opened up a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405869/jna-data-returned-to-starts-at-16th-byte-expected I'll need to explain the issue in more detail then what I can here.