# JNA Data Returned to starts at 16th Byte expected

Tags: java, c, dll, jna

The data I am expecting in the memory is

```
[8 Bytes (long)][20 Bytes (byte[20])][8 Bytes (long)][20 Bytes (byte[20])][8 Bytes(long)][20 Bytes (byte[20])]
```

And the data structures appear to be correct. The issue is the Data in the structures are wrong. The First byte of data expected is actually the **9th Byte.**

**The First 8 expected bytes do not appear at all (the native long)**

I suspect the issue lies in the way I'm setting up my Java object but I am not seeing the issue, personally.

C Union:

```
union _My_SN {
    struct {
        unsigned long    sequence;           
        unsigned char     variant;           
        unsigned char    version;            
        unsigned short    pid;               
    } field;
    struct {
        unsigned long long    ser;
        unsigned char     serName [20]; //16 Characters followed by 4 \0 
        unsigned long long    hw;            
        unsigned char     hwName [20]; //16 Characters followed by 4 \0 
        unsigned long long    oem;           
        unsigned char     oemName [20]; //16 Characters followed by 4 \0
    } sn;
};

typedef union _My_SN My_SN;
```

JNA Java Representation

```
public class My_SN extends Union {

    public field_struct field;
    public sn_struct sn;

    public static class field_struct extends Structure {
        public NativeLong sequence;
        public byte variant;
        public byte version;
        public short pid;

        public field_struct() {
            super();
            setAlignType(ALIGN_NONE);
        }

        protected List getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList("sequence", "variant", "version", "pid");
        }

        public field_struct(NativeLong sequence, byte variant, byte version, short pid) {
            super();
            setAlignType(ALIGN_NONE);
            this.sequence = sequence;
            this.variant = variant;
            this.version = version;
            this.pid = pid;
        }

        public static class ByReference extends field_struct implements Structure.ByReference {
        };

        public static class ByValue extends field_struct implements Structure.ByValue {
        };
    };

    public static class sn_struct extends Structure {

        public long ser;
        public byte[] serName = new byte[20];
        public long hw;
        public byte[] hwName = new byte[20]; 
        public long oem;
        public byte[] oemName = new byte[20];

        public sn_struct() {
            super();
            setAlignType(ALIGN_NONE);
        }

        protected List getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList("ser", "serName", "hw", "hwName", "oem", "oemName");
        }

        public sn_struct(long ser, byte[] serName, long hw, byte[] hwName, long oem, byte[] oemName) {
            super();
            setAlignType(ALIGN_NONE);
            this.ser = ser;
            if (serName.length != this.serName.length) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong array size !");
            }
            this.serName = serName;
            this.hw = hw;
            if (hwName.length != this.hwName.length) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong array size !");
            }
            this.hwName = hwName;
            this.oem = oem;
            if (oemName.length != this.oemName.length) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong array size !");
            }
            this.oemName = oemName;
        }

        public static class ByReference extends sn_struct implements Structure.ByReference {
        };

        public static class ByValue extends sn_struct implements Structure.ByValue {
        };
    };

    public My_SN() {
        super();
        setAlignType(ALIGN_NONE);
    }

    public My_SN(sn_struct sn) {
        super();
        this.sn = sn;
        setAlignType(ALIGN_NONE);
        setType(sn_struct.class);
    }

    public My_SN(field_struct field) {
        super();
        setAlignType(ALIGN_NONE);
        this.field = field;
        setType(field_struct.class);
    }

    public static class ByReference extends My_SN implements Structure.ByReference {
    };

    public static class ByValue extends My_SN implements Structure.ByValue {
    };

}
```

**For the output What i'm getting is**

```
My_SN$sn_struct(allocated@0xf05c0e8 (84 bytes) (shared from allocated@0xf05c0e8 (84 bytes) (shared from allocated@0xf05bc90 (1200 bytes) (shared from auto-allocated@0xf05bc90 (9600 bytes))))) {
  long ser@0=3030343135303230
  byte serName[20]@8=[B@7fe6259a
  long hw@1c=33313841a8130e02
  byte hwName[20]@24=[B@5eaee30f
  long oem@38=ffffffffffffffff
  byte oemName[20]@40=[B@2bbd1e59
}

ser: "3472332698653045296"
serName: "00000009        $0  "
hw: "3688791424436997634"
hwName: "0E0215153024        "
oem: "-1"
oemName: "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF    "

memory dump
[30323035]
[31343030]
[30303030]
[30303039]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[24301515]
[020e13a8]
[41383133]
[30453032]
[31353135]
[33303234]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[ffffffff]
[ffffffff]
[46464646]
[46464646]
[46464646]
[46464646]
[00000000]
```

**What Im Expecting to see (The C DLL doesnt print ser, hw, or oem but in the arrays):**

```
Ser SN: 0205140000000009
H/W SN:     A8130E0215153024
OEM SN:     FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

**This is the C code for this function:**

```
__declspec(dllexport) Bool _cdecl
GetSN(
        DevProgramInfo           * pDevProgInfo,
        unsigned char              sessionID) {


    unsigned char                   * pCmd;
    unsigned short                    cmdLen = 0;
    Platform_Access_Get_SN_Payload     * pBufGetSN;

    pCmd = (unsigned char *)&Cmd;
    pBufGetSN = (Platform_Access_Get_SN_Payload *)&Payload;

    ClearMsgHeader((Message *)pCmd);

    Platform_Get_SN(pCmd, sessionID, &cmdLen, (unsigned char *)pBufGetSN);
    USBWriteToDevice(&pDevProgInfo->deviceInfo, pCmd, &cmdLen);
    USBReadFromDevice(&pDevProgInfo->deviceInfo, pCmd);
    Platform_Get_SN(pCmd, sessionID, &cmdLen, (unsigned char *)pBufGetSN);

    pDevProgInfo->sn.sn.ser = pBufGetSN->resp.ser;
    strcpy((char *)pDevProgInfo->sn.sn.serName, (char *)pBufGetSN->resp.serName);
    pDevProgInfo->sn.sn.hw = pBufGetSN->resp.hw;
    strcpy((char *)pDevProgInfo->sn.sn.hwName, (char *)pBufGetSN->resp.hwName);
    pDevProgInfo->sn.sn.oem = pBufGetSN->resp.oem;
    strcpy((char *)pDevProgInfo->sn.sn.oemName, (char *)pBufGetSN->resp.oemName);

    return TRUE;
}
```

**Test Case?**

```
__declspec(dllexport) bool _cdecl
StructTest(
    My_SN * snInfo){

        snInfo->sn.ser = 0x3030303030303030; //3030303030303030
        strcpy((char *)snInfo->sn.serName, "0123456789ABCDFFFFF"); //1234567890ABCDFFFFF\0
        snInfo->sn.hw = 0x3131313131313131; //11111111
        strcpy((char *)snInfo->sn.hwName, "0123456789ABCDFFFFF"); //1234567890ABCDFFFFF\0
        snInfo->sn.oem = 0x3232323232323232; //22222222
        strcpy((char *)snInfo->sn.oemName, "0123456789ABCDFFFFF"); //1234567890ABCDFFFFF\0

        printf("Ser: %llX\n",snInfo->sn.ser);
        printf("SerName: %s\n",snInfo->sn.serName);
        printf("hw: %llX\n",snInfo->sn.hw);
        printf("hwName: %s\n",snInfo->sn.hwName);
        printf("oem: %llX\n",snInfo->sn.oem);
        printf("oemName: %s\n",snInfo->sn.oemName);

        return My_TRUE;
}
```

**OutPut**

```
Ser: 3030303030303030
SerName: 0123456789ABCDFFFFF
hw: 3131313131313131
hwName: 0123456789ABCDFFFFF
oem: 3232323232323232
oemName: 0123456789ABCDFFFFF
```

**JNA Call**

```
boolean StructTest(My_SN snInfo);

public boolean testSNUnionStruct(My_SN snInfo){
    SHIPFlashProgrammerJNA sfpLibrary = SHIPFlashProgrammerJNA.INSTANCE;
    snInfo.setType(snInfo.sn.getClass());
    boolean result = sfpLibrary.StructTest(snInfo);



    System.out.println("Ser: \"" + Long.toHexString(snInfo.sn.ser) + "\"");
    System.out.println("SerName: \"" + new String(snInfo.sn.serName) + "\"");
    System.out.println("hw: \"" + Long.toHexString(snInfo.sn.hw) + "\"");
    System.out.println("hwName: \"" + new String(snInfo.sn.hwName) + "\"");
    System.out.println("oem: \"" + Long.toHexString(snInfo.sn.oem) + "\"");
    System.out.println("oemName: \"" + new String(snInfo.sn.oemName) + "\"");

    System.out.println(snInfo.toString(true));

    return result;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Ser: "3030303030303030"
SerName: "0123456789ABCDFFFFF "
hw: "3131313100000000"
hwName: "11110123456789ABCDFF"
oem: "464646"
oemName: "222222220123456789AB"

My_SN(auto-allocated@0x1938e3d8 (84 bytes)) {
  My_SN$field_struct field@0=My_SN$field_struct(auto-allocated@0x1938dcb0 (8 bytes)) {
    NativeLong sequence@0=0
    byte variant@4=0
    byte version@5=0
    short pid@6=0
  }
  My_SN$sn_struct sn@0=My_SN$sn_struct(allocated@0x1938e3d8 (84 bytes) (shared from auto-allocated@0x1938e3d8 (84 bytes))) {
    long ser@0=3030303030303030
    byte serName[20]@8=[B@62e8c8
    long hw@1c=3131313100000000
    byte hwName[20]@24=[B@1a0df30
    long oem@38=464646
    byte oemName[20]@40=[B@9cf542
  }
}
memory dump
[30303030] //0000
[30303030] //0000
[30313233] //0123
[34353637] //4567
[38394142] //89AB
[43444646] //CDFF
[46464600] //FFF
[00000000] 
[31313131] //1111
[31313131] //1111
[30313233] //0123
[34353637] //4567
[38394142] //89AB
[43444646] //CDFF
[46464600] //FFF
[00000000]
[32323232] //2222
[32323232] //2222
[30313233] //0123
[34353637] //4567
[38394142] //89AB
```

Comment: Try with a build from latest source on github (fixed issue [223](https://github.com/twall/jna/issues/223)).

Comment: Having troubles getting it to build and pack into a JAR i can plug into my project. I suspect you are also the person I'm in contact with from the JNA mailing list(Same blog links). I provided some info there too.

Comment: It'd be a fair bit clearer if you simply wrote a test case where you fill in the union/struct, write and read it, then compare the union/struct fields and memory against expected values.  It's not clear to me from this description what you're expecting where, other than that "the first 8 bytes seem to be missing".

Comment: Is that was you were looking for? I set some default values in the C code, copied output and then called the same code from JNA.

Comment: I fixed the issue with the text case. It was that I did not need the ALIGN_NONE in My_SN. The text case works. But the Application still is not. Ill keep paying with test cases til i can recreate it with all known values.

Comment: Okay this issue just got extremely weird. I'm creating a JAR file that uses JNA and C generated DLL's to access our hardware and extract Serial Numbers. If I call the code to get the serial number inside of the JNA code (The JAR I'm creating) It works flawlessly. When I package this into a JAR and call the same methods from a program that is using the library I get these issues I'm having above.